# How to use [(ngModel)] for multiple group radio in angular cli?

Tags: angular, radio-button, radio-group

I have >2 group radio button. Every group has >2 radio button. How to get value radio checked.

Answer (score 0):

This is your HTML side:

```
   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input 
          type="radio" 
          name="options" 
          id="option1"
          [(ngModel)]="dataType" value="100">Radio button 1
      </label>
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input 
            type="radio" 
            name="options" 
            id="option2"
            [(ngModel)]="dataType" 
            value="99">Radio button 2
       </label>
    </div>
```

And this one is your .ts component (.ts) side, just declare is as default value.

```
  public dataType: string = "100"; //Value as default (for selected one)
```

Comment: And you can use dataType in your class like this >> this.dataType;